# How to add @testing-library/jest-dom to every testing file in svelte?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, svelte, jest-dom

I am trying to add the jest-dom library to every test file.
I installed that package and made the "jestSetup.js" file and add the package.json as below.

```
"jest":{
   setupFilesAfterEnv:["<rootDir>/jestSetup.js"]
}
```

and jestSetup.js is

```
import @testing-library/jest-dom;
console.log("jest-dom")
```

the test file is

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/svelte";
...
console.log("test")
expect(getByText("success notification")).toHaveClass("success");
...
```

But it says `toHaveClass is not defined` error
And the result of console.log is "jest-dom, jest"
I tested it with jest.config.js again but the result is the same.
I am not sure why it happens.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following?

```json
"jest":{
     setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your node-module should have quotes.

Change this:
`import @testing-library/jest-dom;`

To this:
`import '@testing-library/jest-dom';`